# C++ templating error when used with a typedef

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to compile a steganography package last updated in 2003 using g++ 4.7.2. In a header file, there are the following statements:

```
typedef AudioDataImpl<AuMuLaw,BYTE> AuMuLawAudioData;
inline BYTE AuMuLawAudioData::readValue(BinaryIO *) const {return (io->read8());}
```

There are several other similar statements for reading and writing data of various formats as well. When compiled, the following error message is produced:

> AuData.h:29:13: error: specializing member
>   'AudioDataImpl::readValue' requires
>   'template<>' syntax.

Again, error messages like this is produced for each of the lines in the header file.

I initially thought the compiler was ignorings the typedef statement which would seem to specialize the template appropriately so I replaced the typedef value with the actual template expression but I get the same errors so it isn't the typedef itself that is causing the problem. Did handling of templates change between 2003 and today such that this code no longer compiles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More likely the code was simply not previously compiled on a strictly conforming compiler.

Replace each line with, e.g.

```
template<> inline BYTE AuMuLawAudioData::readValue(BinaryIO *) const {return (io->read8());}
```

and it should be fine. The `typedef` only affects the symbol `AuMuLawAudioData` it does not change the syntax of the overall declaration so you need the `typedef<>` there to indicate it is a template specialisation.